# Levantine Melon

Tags: identification, vines, desert, melons

What is the binomial name of this plant/fruit?

I know for certain it grows in the Levant where it is called jaboor (جعبور). The fruit is commonly sold in markets alongside snake cucumber. The fruit is eaten as a whole (skin, flesh, and seeds). It tastes remotely like cucumber, commonly with hints of sweetness.

Here are the pictures I could find for it:

[image: Fruit sliced up in a plate]

[image: Fruits in a styrofoam box with its vine in the background, next to a container of snake cucumbers]

[image: Fruits in a market]

[image: Box of the fruits]
[image: Fruit growing on the vine]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Cucumis melo variety Chate or Adzhur. Very similar to a carosello cucumber. Where was it grown?